# Magento 2.1 Custom Field at Customer Registration Form Not Working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, registration

I need to add an affiliate email field for customer registration form .

Here are the files I used

app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

```
      <div class="field ">
        <label for="custom_field" class="label"><span><?= __('affiliateEmail') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="affiliate_email" id="affiliate_email" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomField()) ?>" title="<?= __('affiliateEmail') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false,'validate-email':true}">
        </div>
    </div>
```

app/code/vendor/module/setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace Vendor\module\Setup {
    use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
    use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * Install data
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    /**
     * CustomerSetupFactory
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * $attributeSetFactory
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * initiate object
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    /**
     * install data method
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {

        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        /**
         * customer registration form  affiliate email address
         */
        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'affiliate_email', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Affiliate Email',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'affiliate_email')
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();


    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create extension

> step1: /app/code/Customer/Attribute/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Customer_Attribute',
    __DIR__
);
```

> step2: /app/code/Customer/Attribute/Setup/CustomerSetup.php

```
<?php

namespace Customer\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'affiliate_email',
            [
            'label' => 'Affiliate Email',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'input' => 'text',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer', 'affiliate_email')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();


    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

step 3: /app/code/Customer/Attribute/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php

namespace Customer\Attribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Customer\Attribute\Setup\CustomerSetup');
                $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



        }

    }
}
```

> step4: /app/code/Customer/Attribute/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Customer_Attribute" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> step 5:/app/code/Customer/Attribute/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

</config>
```

> step6:app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

```
<div class="field ">
        <label for="custom_field" class="label"><span><?= __('affiliateEmail') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="affiliate_email" id="affiliate_email" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomField()) ?>" title="<?= __('affiliateEmail') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:false,'validate-email':true}">
        </div>
    </div>
```

after run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Hi! What is the table this custom customer registration field saving ? It is not visible in customer entity table.

Comment: `customer_eav_attribute,
eav_entity_attribute`

Comment: Thank you!  I can see custom field is saving in customer_entity_varchar table . Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

Add Custom field in Customer Registration form  Programmatically

Step 1: Create InstallData.php file under app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup directorty and enter below code

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){

                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $customerSetup = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Setup\CustomerSetup');
                $customerSetup->installAttributes($customerSetup);



        }

    }
}
```

Step 2: Create CustomerSetup.php file under app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup directory and enter below code

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\Context;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Framework\App\CacheInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;

class CustomerSetup extends EavSetup {

    protected $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        Context $context,
        CacheInterface $cache,
        CollectionFactory $attrGroupCollectionFactory,
        Config $eavConfig
        ) {
        $this -> eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        parent :: __construct($setup, $context, $cache, $attrGroupCollectionFactory);
    } 

    public function installAttributes($customerSetup) {
        $this -> installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup);
        $this -> installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup);
    } 

    public function installCustomerAttributes($customerSetup) {


        $customerSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'token',
            [
            'label' => 'Token',
            'system' => 0,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  true,
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'input' => 'text',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'token')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('is_required',0)->setData('default_value','')->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout']) -> save();

    } 

    public function installCustomerAddressAttributes($customerSetup) {

    } 

    public function getEavConfig() {
        return $this -> eavConfig;
    } 
}
```

Step 3: Override frontend layout file in our custom module. Create customer_account_create.xml file under app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout directory and enter below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Vendor_Module::form/register.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Step 4: Override customer registration form template file in our custom module to add the custom attribute html. Copy register.phtml file from vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form directory and paste it under app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/form directory. Enter below lines under the form tag.

```
 <?php
//add token attribute
<div class="field">
    <label class="label" for="token"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Token') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="token">
    </div>
</div>
```

This will add the token text field in customer registration form. You can change the field whatever you want

I hope this will help.